# how to dim the current activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-gallery

Is there a way to dim the Current activity when calling the new activity? as in the new activity should be above the previous activity. The new activity that i have is a gallery. It comes when the finish button in the previous activity is clicked. So i want this gallery to be placed above the previous activity

Comment: yea..but instead of dialog i want gallery..i have already the gallery ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the background of your gallery Activity to a transparent color.  You might need to create a custom theme and more details can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

This is probably going to be completely transparent, so not quite what you want.  But, for example:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
```

Comment: This is kind off what i wanted. Can it be blurred? thats what i need instead of completely transparent

Comment: You can try Theme.Dialog.  Otherwise, you might need to create your own custom theme.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if you could overlay two activities on top of each other. However, in order to achieve the effect that you mentioned, you could use a customized dialog to popup within your main gallery activity, and then set the rest of the screen as blurred, with the use of window manager. For an example of this, you can see: http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-blurring-and-dimming-background-windows-from-dialogs/