# Dim the background of an activity in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that I am showing an activity over another activity with transparent background but I want to show the same with dim background. How can I achieve this?

Comment: could possibly help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7132265/1007273

Comment: Hey hovanessyan, I am doing the same through which I got the transparent bckground, I want this transparent background turns dim.

Comment: You can go through the API Demos.Its not accurately what you want but though,the one with name "Translucent Blur" there might help you.

Answer (score 28):

Here is the complete code:

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
    layoutParams.dimAmount = 0.75f;
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

Put this code right after you inflate the layout.

Answer (score 5):

Create a xml under drawable folder names as window_dim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

Set main layout attribute in xml as bellow -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
...

android:foreground="@drawable/window_dim"
android:orientation="vertical"
... >
```

In activity set main layout as bellow -

```
mainLayout.getForeground().setAlpha(180);
```

Comment: Easy solution but doesn't work before api 23. Any way for before api 23 ?

Comment: Wasting time if you are targeting lower API< 23. thanks @ysfcyln

Comment: https://try2explore.com/questions/10149293

Better alternative for API 18+ , Check this from this page

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams wp = getWindow().getAttributes();
wp.dimAmount = 0.75f;
```